# session variable is not affecting on view when i create and update session variable in partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatables, partial-views

I am currently developing inline editable jquery data-table in that i call partial view to call data from server side. data is coming successfully.

problem : in partial view i am setting session variable value but in view that session variable value is not updated. here is my code structure.

**code on view** :

```
function getFixedHours() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var result = $('#demo');
            var date11 = $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Home", "partialindex")',
                tyoe: 'GET',
                data: { date: date11, type: 1 },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#demo').html(data);
                    $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
                        "bPaginate": false,
                        "aoColumnDefs": [
                             { 'bFilter': false, 'aTargets': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] },
                             { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] },
                             { "bSearchable": false, "aTargets": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] }

                        ]
                    }).makeEditable({
                        sUpdateURL: "/Home/UpdateData/",
                        "aoColumns": [
                                        null,
                                          @{
                                              if (Session["mon"]!=null)
                                                  {
                                                      <text>
                                                    {  indicator: 'Saving...',
                                                        tooltip: 'Click to select town',
                                                        loadtext: 'loading...',
                                                        type: 'time',
                                                        submit: 'Save Changes'
                                                    }
                                                      </text>
                                                  }
                                              else {
                                                  <text> null  </text>
                                                   }

                                          }  
                                    ]
                    });
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve data.');
                }

            });
        })
    }
```

**Partial View**:

```
<table id="myDataTable" class="table">
    <thead>

        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Site")
            </th>


            <th>
                @if (!dayLocked)
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["mon"] = "true";

                }
                else
                {
                    <text>Locked</text>
                    Session.Remove("mon");
                }
                @Html.DisplayName(mon.ToString("ddd"))
                @Html.DisplayName(mon.ToString("dd-MMM"))
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**i am set session variable session["mon"] value in partial view but this value is not affected in view**

**note: this is piece of code and i am new in mvc.**

Comment: If the content of the session is a simple type, why not try to use a Viewbag?

Comment: ' tyoe: 'GET'' is incurrect and why don't change session in "partialindex"

Answer (score 1):

Setting the a session variable doesn't take effect until the next request. As a result, you cannot set a session variable in a partial view and then access that in the main view. However, you should not be setting anything in the session in any view, really, because views should be devoid of logic. Obviously, that's a goal rather than a true restriction because views will inevitably have *some* logic, but only when it's truly necessary. Here, it's not. The place for accessing the session is in the controller.

Comment: then what should i do because i want to change my view when accordingly partial view is change. i m try to set session variable when its call partialindex method but obviously it not affected my view

Comment: If the partial view is being changed via AJAX, it's already too late for your main view. That has long since been rendered and returned to the client. If you need to update some piece of that, you'll need to do so with JavaScript or another AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is when you request for the view, the code in the view is executed and it returns the html. The html is generated according to the session variable as it was while this call. After the view is rendered in the browser, it calls the patrial via ajax. So in this flow, if the session variable is changed, it cannot modify the HTML of your main view as the part of code is not executed in this flow. If you request the main view again, this time the updated session value will be available. So the HTML will be generated according to the updated session variable.

Comment: then what should i do because i want to change my view when accordingly  partial view is change. i m try to set session variable when its call partialindex method but obviously it not affected my view.

Answer (score 0):

Main View :

```
var isDayLocked =false;
function getFixedHours() {
if(isDayLocked){
    //do your stuff
}
}
```

PartialView:

```
<script>
isDayLocked = '@!Model.DayLocked'=='False';
</script>
```

Why use sessions in the client side when you have to use javascript variables?